# Custom popup in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, jquery

I have created a custom popup in list page .. I need to open the popup after 4 sec of every product addtocart.

**And auto close the popup after 4 sec.**

some time the popup suddenly closed within 4 sec....

How to slove this ...

```
    $.ajax({
     url: BASE_URL + this.options.posturl,
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
     data: {productId: productId},
      success: function (response) {
       $("#custom-popup").hide();
   if (response['content']) {
    $("#custom-popup").html(response['content']);
         setTimeout(function () {
           $("#custom-popup").show();
          setInterval(function () {
          $("#custom-popup").hide();
          }, 4000);
         }, 4000);

 }
            }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if any query.

Comment: Your answer is same as my question..what is the change???? @Rohan Hapani

Comment: Remove $("#custom-popup").hide(); at success.

Comment: Can i remove these lines in my code ?                                                                                     setInterval(function () {
          $("#custom-popup").hide();
          }, 4000);